# What does the error "iTunes could not restore the iPod 'NAME' because the backup could not be saved on the computer." mean?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, backup

My iPod was acting up (the clock was going out of sync, it often became unresponsive to touch) so before contacting Apple I decided to try a Backup & Restore.

I plugged in my iPod and pressed "Backup iPod".  It did it fine, it seemed, and let me know when it was done.  Then I clicked "Restore" and after a few of the normal errors (11 and 14) I force-restored it using the Home & Power buttons.

When it was finally restored I selected "Restore from Backup" and picked my latest Backup.  That's where the problem starts... it keeps reaching 2/3 of the way done and then this error appears: 
"iTunes could not restore the iPod 'NAME' because the backup could not be saved on the computer."

The problem occurs with all of my backups, and persists after a computer restart and after trying a different USB port (just in case.)

I looked around at several forums and found no one with a similar problem.  The error seems to usually appear for other people when the backup is actually being created, not when the iPod is being restored *to* a backup like it does in this case.

I hope this was enough information.  Thanks to any help you guys might be able to give :)

Cheers!
- Lindsay

Comment: Do you know what the permissions are on the Backup folder in `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/`?

Comment: Agreed. Definitely sounds like a permissions issue. Get info on the folder described above and let us know what permissions are set.

Comment: What OS are you running? Did you try to put the iPod in recovery mode?

Comment: I have the same problem but my permissions have everything set to allow except for "special permissions"

Comment: I have been having the same problems since I added a second user account. I can now only backup my iPad 2 iPhone 4 via my newer user account. I have tried to modify ACL permissions and nothing has changed.

Comment: Additional info for this old post: Many times, iTunes will create a snapshot backup right before performing a restore. Likely there is a permissions issue or disk space issue happening during this safety backup process. Since the time of the original post, iTunes has changed the wording to mention available disk space if that is the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I hopefully have a solution to this issue. I also had this problem, and I believe it's because you have insuffient disk space and iTunes being a large program requires so much disk space to be available in order to perform these tasks.

Therefore, iTunes will bring up the error after reaching 2/3 of the way and then the error appears: **"iTunes could not restore the iPod/iphone 'NAME' because the backup could not be saved on the computer."** The backup you did is there because you're obviously selecting it when "restoring from backup". So free up some disk space and redo the **"restore from backup"** and it should complete the process without any errors.